# loop all sheet-not working, only re perform on single sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I would like the code below to work on all (20) sheets on the workbook,but it only work on 1 sheet and repeatedly copy/paste on that 1 sheet, any advice please?

Much appreciated your time

```
Sub Copylastcolumn()

Dim ws As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Cells(6, "BJ").End(xlToLeft).Column

Cells(6, LastCol).Resize(LastRow - 5).Copy Cells(6, LastCol + 1)

Columns(LastCol).Copy
Columns(LastCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the object (ws) you are working with

```
Sub Copylastcolumn()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   LastCol = ws.Cells(6, "BJ").End(xlToLeft).Column

   ws.Cells(6, LastCol).Resize(LastRow - 5).Copy ws.Cells(6, LastCol + 1)

   ws.Columns(LastCol).Copy
   ws.Columns(LastCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next ws

End Sub
```

You could also use `With...End With` to be more elegant